# migration using csv and yml for multivalued image field

Tags: 8, files, migrations, plugins

some problem with sub-process plugin. Here are my yml and csv files.

```
uuid: c0948690-b539-421e-b306-6a49d14afd64
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: migration_multivalues
class: null
field_plugin_method: null
cck_plugin_method: null
migration_tags: null
migration_group: default
label: migration_two_files
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/drupal/sites/default/files/tasktwo.csv'
  header_row_count: 1
  ids:
    - id
  constants:
    file_source: 'filesandimages/'
    file_destination: 'importedfilesandimages/'
process:
  title: title
  body: body
  field_multivalue_image:
    -
      plugin: explode
      delimiter: ','
      source: image
    -
      plugin: single_value
      handle_multiples: TRUE
    -
      plugin: sub_process
      key: '@fids'
      process:
        fids:
          plugin: concat
          source:
            - constants/file_source
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
  default_bundle: article
migration_dependencies:
  required: {  }
  optional: {  }
```

csv file

```
id,title,body,image
1,"Faculty one","One","dolon.jpg,intern5.png"
2,"Faculy two","Two","intern5.png"
3,"Faculty three","Three","dolon.jpg"
4,"Faculty four","Four","intern5.png,intern6.png"
5,"Faculty five","Five","dolon.jpg,intern5.png"
```

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in Drupal\migrate\Plugin\migrate\process\SubProcess->transform() (line 204 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\core\modules\migrate\src\Plugin\migrate\process\SubProcess.php)
>
> Error: Unsupported operand types in Drupal\migrate\Plugin\migrate\process\SubProcess->transform() (line 204 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\core\modules\migrate\src\Plugin\migrate\process\SubProcess.php)

Comment: `source`: `- constants/file_source` `- 0`

Comment: did you get it working somehow ? I have a similar problem with comma separated values in as a source field value. I tried with explode->deepen->sub_process but it will not work