# Migrate a two-textfield field

Tags: 9, migrations

I'm looking to migrate a text field from Drupal 6 to Drupal 9. The field has two text fields.

The table description  returned by `describe content_field_telfono ;`  is the following.

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| vid | int(10) unsigned | NO | PRI | 0 |  |
| nid | int(10) unsigned | NO | MUL | 0 |  |
| field_telfono_value | varchar(10) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| delta | int(10) unsigned | NO | PRI | 0 |  |

The table content returned by `select * from content_field_telfono limit 0,2;` is the following.

| vid | nid | field_telfono_value | delta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 48 | 48 | xxxxxxxxx | 0 |
| 48 | 48 | xxxxxxxxx | 1 |

I found examples to migrate a multi-value.
I tried with the following migration.

```yml
  field_school_phone:
    plugin: sub_process
    source: field_telfono
    process:
      value: field_telfono_value
```

Comment: Did you just try a simple map first? source: destination

Comment: How can I make it? 
The only examples I find in the core modules it's to map constants values.
Thanks.

Comment: Make what? Simply try doing field_school_phone: field_telfono and running it again. There are several several examples in core for migrations, as well as contributed modules like Migrate Plus.

Answer (score -1):

have you seen this? [migration using csv and yml for multivalued image field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/293284/migration-using-csv-and-yml-for-multivalued-image-field)

anyway i think if you have the multivalued field separated by commas, it should work directly

Comment: Thanks for helping out. This appears to be a comment rather than an answer.